# How to add a fading effect for my JS slideshow?

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow, fading

I have this slideshow JS code that switches images in a `div` depending on the time we want. However, how can I add a fade in/fade out effect instead of a basic transition with no animation? I am doing this without jQuery, just plain javascript. Here is the link: https://en.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/js-library-exatreojs-slideshow-library/2950604004

here is the code:

```js
var slideShow = function(container, time) {
            container = document.getElementById(container);
            this.images = [];
            this.curImage = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < container.childElementCount; i++) {
                this.images.push(container.children[i]);
                this.images[i].style.display = "none";
            }

            // Handle going to to the next slide
            var nextSlide = function() {
                for (var i = 0; i < this.images.length; i++) {
                    this.images[i].style.display = "none";
                }
                this.images[this.curImage].style.display = "block";
                this.curImage++;
                if (this.curImage >= this.images.length) {
                    this.curImage = 0;
                }
                window.setTimeout(nextSlide.bind(document.getElementById(this)), time);
                // old code: window.setTimeout(nextSlide.bind(this), time);
            };

            nextSlide.call(this);
        
        };
        slideShow("slideshow", 1000);
        // old code: slideShow(document.getElementById("slideshow"), 1000);
```

```html
    <div id="slideshow">
        <img src="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/animals/birds_rainbow-lorakeets.png" alt="Rainbow lorakeets" />
        <img src="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/animals/butterfly.png" alt="Butterfly" />
        <img src="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/animals/cat.png" alt="Cat" />
        <img src="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/animals/crocodiles.png" alt="Crocodiles" />
        <img src="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/animals/fox.png" alt="Fox" />

    </div>
```

Comment: To add fade in you would need to gradually increase opacity of the new image with a timer from 0 to 1. So there would probably need to be two images positioned absolutely, the one that has lower z-index is being replaced with another image with higher z-index and on this image would be the opacity animation.

Comment: thanks! getting me on track!

Comment: Also, you'll probably want to do the gradual fade in/out via a loop that contains a setTimeout call to the actual code the does that fade. Upon each iteration of the loop, the setTimeout creates a small delay before calling the function that does the fade. This way the change in opacity doesn't happen all at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this method, if you don't mind that display is always block and I just change opacity of image. So the container has to be **relatively** positioned and imgs should be absolute

```js
var slideShow = function(container, time) {
  container = document.getElementById(container);
  this.images = [];
  this.curImage = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < container.childElementCount; i++) {
    this.images.push(container.children[i]);
    this.images[i].style.opacity = 0;
  }

  // Handle going to to the next slide
  var nextSlide = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.images.length; i++) {
      if (i!=this.curImage) this.images[i].style.opacity = 0;
    }
    this.images[this.curImage].style.opacity = 1;
    this.curImage++;
    if (this.curImage>=this.images.length) this.curImage=0;
    window.setTimeout(nextSlide.bind(document.getElementById(this)), time);
    // old code: window.setTimeout(nextSlide.bind(this), time);
  };

  nextSlide.call(this);

};
slideShow("slideshow", 1000);
// old code: slideShow(document.getElementById("slideshow"), 1000);
```

```css
img {
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="slideshow">
  <img src="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/animals/birds_rainbow-lorakeets.png" alt="Rainbow lorakeets" />
  <img src="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/animals/butterfly.png" alt="Butterfly" />
  <img src="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/animals/cat.png" alt="Cat" />
  <img src="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/animals/crocodiles.png" alt="Crocodiles" />
  <img src="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/animals/fox.png" alt="Fox" />

</div>
```

Comment: is it possible to make an "option", if I want the fade or not?

Comment: of course. This fade effect achieved by transition: 0.5s. So you can create button that will add class with transition 0; to every element in slideshow and there will be no fade effect

Comment: I get that (Not trying to sound bossy/mean or anything, I love what you did and it really helps me for my project), but for example, if I want to add like a sliding animation, how can I achive it?

Comment: If you want different types of animations you, probably, should consider using some existing library for it. But if you want to make everything from the scratch, then yes. To do that you should add to css **tansition:.5s** change style.transformX instead of opacity. Set it to "100%" for block you want to slide away and 0 for all other